# About the $k$-th derivative of the Riemann Zeta Function

Tags: limits, derivatives, riemann-zeta

Good morning! I'm writing about the fractional derivatives of $\zeta(s)$ right now and got a question. When computing the $k$-th derivative I arrive at

$$\zeta^{(k)}(s)=\mathrm{e}^{i \pi k} \sum_{n\ge2} \frac{\log ^{k} n}{n^{s}}$$

Now I would like to know one thing. When taking derivatives it's always about taking a limit. How can I justify the interchange of limits when taking each derivative? Help/proofs/etc. would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The direct way is to prove it for $\zeta^{(k-1)}(s)$ then $$|\frac{\zeta^{(k-1)}(s+h)-\zeta^{(k-1)}(s)}{h}-\sum_n (-1)^k n^{-s}\log^k n|$$ $$\le \sum_n |n^{-s} (\frac1h \int_s^{s+h}( n^{-x} \log^k n-\log^k n)dx)|\le \sum_n |n^{-s}| Ch \log^{k+1} n$$

and hence $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\zeta^{(k-1)}(s+h)-\zeta^{(k-1)}(s)}{h}=\sum_n (-1)^k n^{-s}\log^k n$$

Comment: How do you get those inequalities? A few more steps or some explanaition would be nice :)

Comment: $n^{-s} (\frac1h \int_s^{s+h}( n^{-x} \log^k n-\log^k n)dx= \frac{n^{-s}\log^{k-1}n-n^{-s-h}\log^{k-1}n}{h} - n^{-s}\log^{k}n$

Comment: And from what does the second inequality follow?

Comment: Which one ? $\le \sum_n |n^{-s}| Ch \log^{k+1} n$ ? It is the same : $n^{-x} \log^k n-\log^k n$ is the integral of the derivative. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Yes, that one. But where does the $h$ come from? Could you elaborate a bit more please?